# CSS3 animated target selector

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/cpbCk

I'm having a bit of trouble here.
I want the div scale set to 0 and when targeted to scale in, but when I tried it didn't work.

**CSS**

```
/* Content Area */
.content div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #333;
    border: 1em solid #555;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

/* hide unselected targets */
.content div:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
/* display selected target */
:target {
    display: inherit;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<article id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="about">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at feugiat odio. Proin sit amet eros ac diam tempus tempor. Fusce gravida ut nisi in consectetur. Sed hendrerit sapien id metus adipiscing, id vehicula lacus fermentum. Proin mollis facilisis erat, eu sollicitudin diam scelerisque ut. Phasellus non mollis nisl. Vestibulum ac mi quis metus mollis fermentum. Donec pharetra consequat lacinia. Vestibulum porta tortor purus, non fermentum turpis congue eget. Nulla varius augue dolor, at pellentesque diam volutpat in. Vestibulum vitae ligula eu eros tristique accumsan. Mauris sagittis iaculis lorem id egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Cras faucibus dolor turpis, ac ultrices dolor rhoncus a.

            <p>Etiam aliquam magna vitae hendrerit accumsan. Nam venenatis risus a tempor semper. Nullam ac est nec dolor pellentesque laoreet ac ac nisi. Ut sit amet magna nunc. Vestibulum orci ipsum, pretium nec venenatis vel, lacinia et magna. Proin dignissim dui ligula, eget pretium nisl ultrices eu. Etiam sit amet nunc non nisl scelerisque dignissim a sed sapien.</p>

            <p>Quisque auctor sit amet mi sed porta. Fusce nec erat eros. Suspendisse et diam sit amet quam pretium sollicitudin quis nec enim. Nam fermentum risus dui, non volutpat dolor pellentesque nec. Quisque interdum, neque eu feugiat hendrerit, risus augue malesuada mauris, non vestibulum ante erat quis purus. Nunc scelerisque sapien vel leo bibendum, vel dapibus ipsum ultricies. Cras commodo lacus quis nunc eleifend iaculis. Nam adipiscing ipsum non justo ultrices, sit amet vestibulum urna vehicula. Praesent porttitor neque et dictum euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam adipiscing, neque ut dictum ultricies, dui odio aliquet dui, ac rhoncus neque nulla a enim.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut purus leo, varius pellentesque vestibulum at, lobortis quis est. Suspendisse mattis leo vel eros faucibus adipiscing. Phasellus sed nisl eu lectus blandit dignissim vel id nibh. Donec rutrum felis urna, sed elementum urna venenatis quis. Praesent vel tortor sed felis sodales lobortis eget eget nulla. Aliquam bibendum elit eu nunc facilisis, varius tempor lectus mattis. Aenean sed aliquet orci. Aliquam viverra molestie ultrices.

            <p>Nullam luctus imperdiet risus, vel convallis massa interdum id. In ultricies pulvinar libero vitae sodales. Fusce eleifend varius tincidunt. Nulla sed blandit nibh. Ut sollicitudin, metus et sagittis tincidunt, nisl felis ultricies ante, eu dapibus massa odio sed nunc. Pellentesque semper eros dui, ac mollis nunc dictum non. Quisque ultrices sapien at velit pellentesque, at lacinia est commodo. Morbi commodo in neque eu tempor. Curabitur eu mattis diam, eu tristique mauris.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse sit amet lacus rutrum, faucibus augue vitae, euismod nibh. Mauris aliquet nisi in nibh aliquam, et ullamcorper turpis mattis. Vestibulum ut hendrerit libero, eu ultricies odio. Etiam sodales vehicula dignissim. Vestibulum libero tellus, luctus sed imperdiet quis, malesuada sed nunc. In aliquet pellentesque erat pellentesque fringilla. Aenean egestas ipsum eu nunc auctor, nec vestibulum est varius. Integer convallis, orci sit amet sagittis hendrerit, purus ligula dictum dolor, in lobortis ligula lacus pulvinar lorem. Sed pulvinar porttitor egestas. Duis ac ante ipsum. Donec sem odio, sollicitudin in fermentum egestas, gravida sed diam. Nam condimentum augue ut ligula dapibus sodales. Donec blandit sem non cursus aliquam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="services">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus posuere porta suscipit. In ac purus quis lectus blandit rutrum eu vitae nisi. Nunc vel ante at enim imperdiet ultrices et non erat. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis nulla. Ut quis turpis sit amet enim volutpat tincidunt. Vivamus vel ornare neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis tincidunt mi et ipsum cursus, vitae tincidunt ipsum fringilla. Integer eu mollis elit, in tincidunt neque.

            <p>Maecenas ac est gravida, iaculis mauris vitae, tempus enim. Mauris ut nisi dapibus, commodo massa sed, iaculis augue. Cras sit amet leo libero. Mauris ac dui lorem. Aenean velit risus, ornare molestie neque ac, feugiat cursus tellus. Duis commodo lacinia felis, vitae aliquam mauris consectetur cursus. Donec arcu orci, sollicitudin eu lacus id, ultricies sollicitudin ligula. Vivamus ac egestas ipsum. Duis aliquam suscipit tristique. Vestibulum aliquet bibendum arcu, in adipiscing arcu sagittis ut. Aenean in leo risus. Morbi vitae nibh in eros accumsan consequat in ac lacus. Maecenas pretium mattis justo non euismod. Sed vel velit sollicitudin, posuere mi nec, dictum lectus.</p>

            <p>Nullam nisl nisi, dignissim ultrices cursus id, aliquet vel purus. Praesent velit purus, pharetra id eros id, viverra ultricies velit. Phasellus sed lacinia neque, at dictum odio. Mauris eget accumsan augue, ac imperdiet magna. Proin commodo sem id purus vulputate mollis. Nunc a dignissim urna. Nam facilisis, lectus sit amet blandit egestas, velit tortor imperdiet massa, eu elementum lorem dolor nec diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus sit amet nisl turpis. Nulla vel nulla ut odio feugiat ultrices. Ut id consequat sem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems there, first being that `.content div` has a higher specificity than `:target`, consequently the rules in `:target` are being overridden by the ones from `.content div`. You can fix this by using a selector like `.content div:target`

The other problem is that changing the display state breaks transitions. One workaround would be to use keyframe animations:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxHkf

You might notice some flashing, but that only happens on codepen, it's fine when used standalone.

```
.content div:target {
    -webkit-animation: scale 300ms ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: scale 300ms ease-out forwards;
    animation: scale 300ms ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes scale {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes scale {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use a different technique for hiding the elements instead of `display`, for example using `clip`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eofrz

```
.content div:not(:target) {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

.content div:target {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
}
```

And one thing that I've just noticed with a smaller window, is that except for IE, all browsers seem to target the center (more or less) of the scaled element, which is probably not what you want. One quick workaround would be to set `transform-origin` to `50% 0`:

```
.content div {
    ...
    -webkit-origin: 50% 0;
    -moz-origin: 50% 0;
    -o-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
```

Now it will of course transform from the top, however this is currently the only workaround I've found for this problem.

Comment: One question, any special reason for adding the `clip` property? seems to work well even without that.

Comment: @Harry This is to hide the animation from scale `1` to `0` when another element is targeted. I just assumed that this is what the author wants, because using `display: none` would have the same effect. However I've just realized that using `height` and `overflow` isn't necessary, there was just a glitch in the Firefox nightly that I was testing. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to set the `scale(0)` to all elements that are `not(:target)` and then transition it to `scale(1)` on `:target` like the below.

As pointed out by **ndm** in his answer, changing display state breaks transitions and hence changing from `display: none` to `display: block` will make the transition effects to not happen.

To overcome this you can modify your code like below. It uses `translate` property to move the contents out of the display area. (**Note:** This would make the slide-in to happen from the left, but I couldn't find any better alternates).

```
.content div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #333;
    border: 1em solid #555;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
/* hide unselected targets */
 .content div:not(:target) {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
    -o-transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%) scale(0);
}
/* display selected target */
 :target {
    transform: translate(0%) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translate(0%) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translate(0%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%) scale(1);
}
```

[**CodePen Link**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/kuEHc)